# Does overriding a Spring property update the properties that reference it?

Tags: spring

My assumption is no, but I'd like to confirm.

Say I have as application.properties:

```
redis.host = localhost
redis.port = 6379
redis.address = ${redis.host}:${redis.port}
```

If I then have in my override.properties:

```
redis.port = 7777
```

I don't suppose that will automatically update redis.address as well? My assumption is no... but it would be nice to know for sure.

Comment: That depends on how things are being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you are right, the properties get overloaded for the ones defined. The address and host wont get overwritten.

```
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/io/support/PropertiesLoaderSupport.java
```

Comment: Figured as such. Do you have a suggestion for what best practices are in such a scenario?

Comment: There is no single best practice. best one is which is good for your use case. You can configure CustomBehaviour of property loading by providing a bean of type PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. You can control order and overriding properties of the config files using this.